# Why can my code not find the AngularJS $interval?

Tags: angularjs

My AngularJS Code is trying to call $interval and there's a problem in VS2013 saying not found.  Here's the code:

```
var appRun = [
    '$rootScope',
    function (
        $rootScope
        ) {

        // This does not work
        $interval(userService.isAuthenticated(), 5000);
        // This works
        $rootScope.$interval(userService.isAuthenticated(), 5000);

    }]

app.run(appRun);
```

Can someone tell me why the call to $interval. ... does not work. Why do I need to put $rootScope before it ?

Comment: You must not. But you need to inject the $interval service to be able to use it, just like you inject the $rootScope service. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$interval` is an Angular service that you need to inject just as you inject `$rootScope`:

```
var appRun = [
    '$rootScope', '$interval',
    function ($rootScope, $interval) {
        $interval(userService.isAuthenticated(), 5000);
    }]

app.run(appRun);
```

Regarding why `$rootScope.$interval` seems to work - you may have attached the `$interval` service to the `$rootScope` on some other part of your application. It's not built-in on the `$rootScope`.

In any case, it should be used via injection.